# htaccess want to cut folder in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

i am looking for a htaccess rule, which cuts foldernames in an url now when im clicking on a product after search i got a 404 path ist

DOMAIN.COM/magento/index.php/catalog/product/view/s/sony-ericsson-w810i/

what i want is that i click and get this path:

DOMAIN:COM/magento/index.php/sony-ericsson-w810i.html

so its just about cutting the catalog/product/view/s/ part.... this part is static but the name behind (in this case the mobilephone) is dynamic...

can someone give me the right htacces rewrite rule?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The following rule should achieve what you are looking for

```
RewriteRule ^magento/index.php/catalog/product/view/s/(.*)$ /magento/index.php/$1.html [R=302,L]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works.

Comment: What happens when you have that added (after the `RewriteEngine On` line)?

Comment: added it after the rewrite on but didnt change anything in the url but i think now it seems to be a problem in php/database so i'm going fix this seems cleaner but thanks for help :)

Comment: Would you be able to post the contents of the htacces file?

Comment: the whole file has 210 lines its a normal magento htaccess i just added

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^magento.clean/index.php/catalog/product/view/s/(.*)$ /magento.clean/index.php/$1.html [R=302,L]

the code i added is just the rewrite rule rest is for placement :)

Comment: Is the folder name called `magento.clean`?